# Displaying a placeholder when using jQuery UI sortable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I have declared a sortable list of items with jQuery UI in a bootstrap page.

```
$("#ReportContainer").sortable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
});
```

Each draggable element is a column e.g. col-md-12 down to col-md-4. When I drag an element I want the placeholder to retain the col-md-x of the element I am dragging. If I set a placehollder css I have to default it to one size between 12 and 4. By Default jQuery just adds the .ui-sortable-placeholder to the classes already there which would do what I want apart from that it also adds a style="display: none" which means I can't see my placeholder.

Currently the placeholder looks like this

```
 <div class="col-md-x ui-sortable-placeholder" style="display: none"></div>
```

If I set a placeholder it will throw away all col-md-x classes and just use that. e.g.

```
<div class="myPlaceholder"></div>
```

Does anyone have a work around for this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. Are you using the placeholder option in the sortable? Your jQuery doesn't reflect that.

Comment: I am not using the option because when I do it overwrites all the other classes of the placeholder and I lose the the col-md-12, col-md-4 or whatever it was that was defining the correct width of the placeholder. When I don't define 'placeholder' it will just add ui-sortable-placeholder to all the other classes already in the div. Basically, I want the placeholder to keep the classes of the element being dragged which I don't see how to do if I define a placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

Ended up setting the placeholder to visible when I start dragging an element. This allows me to keep the original classes and display the placeholder.

```
$("#ReportContainer").sortable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
  /*placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',*/
  start: function(e, ui){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
        ui.placeholder.css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```js
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        items: ".row > div",
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        over: function(event, ui) {
          var cl = ui.item.attr('class');
          $('.ui-state-highlight').addClass(cl);
      }
    }).disableSelection();
```

Working fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmb23z36/3/

Comment: If you want the height, then you need to calculate the height of ui.item and apply to placeholder in the same function. If want to remove the added class remove form the STOP Event.